# Change default name and icon for published setup.exe in Microsoft Visual C#

Tags: c#, icons

excuse me if it's a pretty silly question but I really can't figure it out, and I did not find it answered already.

I just made a basic desktop app in Visual C#, when I publish it by default I get a setup.exe file with default icon... How do I change name and icon?
I have already set a custom .ico file in Proprieties>Application>Icon and manifest, but it's the same...

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to change the icon of the Setup-file or the Application Executable?

Comment: Renaming is simple, just use Windows Explorer.  The icon is pre-cooked, I think it is stored in bootstrapper\engine\setup.bin in the Windows SDK install directory.  Renaming this file to setup.exe and opening it in VS might work, you'd have to try.  Be sure to make a backup copy.

Comment: Well it seems to be the setup file since the name is setup.exe, but indeed it's just the application executable (cause no installation is needed).. I know I can simply rename it but I would like to set it before the publish process (so I don't have do rename it every time..)